# Given a list of words, identify all identical substrings of length 4 or greater

Tags: python, algorithm, counter, frequency

Let's say I have a list of foreign words:

1. ilikuwa
2. alikuwa
3. nilifundisha
4. anafundisha
5. tunasoma
6. tulisoma

I want to identify within this list of words, substrings of length 4 or greater that are common in the words.  For example, the word "kuwa", "fundisha", and "soma" would all fall under this category.

Then, when I do frequency analysis re:

```
cnt = Counter()
for lines in list:
    cnt[words]
print cnt.most_common(2000)
```

I want those substrings to be counted the number of times they appear in the overall list...such that the final output for: print cnt.most_common(3) would be something like.

1. kuwa - 2
2. fundisha - 2
3. soma- 2
4. ilikuwa- 1
   ...etc

I'm at a complete loss for how to go about doing this, though.  Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't the first result be `likuwa - 2`?

Comment: Shit, Tim, you're right.  That will definitely be a problem, because 'kuwa' is the verb root, and 'li' just indicates past tense.  Perhaps there has to be some condition to ignore "li", "na", "ta", and "ji" [past, present, future, and reflexive] unless they're doubled like ililipa in which case 'lipa' is the verb root.

Comment: Looks like you should look into natural language processors instead of regexes. Human languages are not a good fit for regex...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're already using a `Counter`, so all that's missing is a way to generate the substrings of any given string. If that bit is in a function somewhere that takes a string and the minimum length of a substring, your counting logic can be a one-liner with help from `itertools.chain`:

```
cnt = Counter(chain.from_iterable(substrings(line, 4) for line in lines))
cnt.most_common(2000)
```

Which leaves the problem of working out how to generate those substrings. The easiest way to do this is to loop over the possible sizes of substrings, and then loop over the string and give back the slice starting at each successive position in the string, and having the given length (but since slices in Python take a start and an end index, we need to do some slice arithmetic to make that work):

```
def substrings(s, min_length=1):
   for length in range(min_length, len(s)+1):
     for start in range(len(s) - min_length + 1):
        yield s[start:start+length]
```

Comment: I understand how this would work, but I'm not sure how to get cnt.most_common(2000) to print the actual strings, rather than an iterator object.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Parseltongue use `chain.from_iterable` instead of `chain`; I've fixed it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If efficiency matters, I believe you will need a [Suffix Array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array).

As shown in the wiki, with a suffix array you can count the number of appears of any substring in O(m+logN), in which m is the length of the substring and N is the total length of all words.

Yet you still need to enumerate all substrings of each word. I don't think a O(N*N) enumeration is avoidable in the worst case. But with a dict() to avoid multiple checking of duplicated substrings will certainly improve the performance in average cases.